# Cannot TCP outside of local area network to Internet, but can ping machines on the Internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet, ping

#### TL;DR

I can ping outside, can only TCP inside network.

#### More details:

I’ve been trying to fix up my dad’s custom built computer (Windows 7) I built for him. After a few months, the Internet got really slow, and we got a new network adapter—USB Wi-Fi‚after it got too slow. Now that that somehow has prevented the Internet from loading. I even live booted CentOS 7, and it had the same issue. In the past, a wired Ethernet connection did work.

I tried resetting Winsock, restarting the computer etc… with no success. I just now reformatted the PC with a fresh copy of Windows 7, and reinstalled just the network adapter drivers and nothing has changed.

It connects to the network computers fine, even loaded a web page hosting on my PC. It can ping Google, Yahoo, my websites, etc, and perform a traceroute too. However, any outbound—haven’t tested inbound—TCP connections outside the network just result in timing out. Other computer on the network are fine, and the adapter works fine when placed in other computers.

I set up RDP and attempted to RDP into the computer, it hung on establishing secure connection, and likewise to my own. I think it can connect, but is unable to receive data?

Comment: If you plug in an Ethernet cable, does it connect outbound to any website?

Comment: Any non-ethernet devices, even these USB wireless devices run like a separate box compared to onboard or expansion NICs. There might be some sort of firewall or port-forwarding settings on that thing. Try to check if it has a web interface, like 192.168.100.1 or something like that, see its manual and check if it has this type of settings.

Comment: You didn't describe your network configuration in details, what kind of equipment separates your "inside" network from outside? Is that second computer you have able to connect to the Internet? Did you try to call your provider and describe the issue? Maybe there's a problem on his side, or perhaps he is blocking your access on purpose.

Comment: I suppose it could be a path MTU problem. On your Dad's Win7 box, on the primary interface it's using to connect to the Internet now, set the MTU down to something lower like 1300 and see if it starts connect fine. If it does, try higher MTUs until you find where it breaks, then lower it back down to the highest MTU that works.